# Downgrade latest version of Vite to version @2.5.10

Tags: javascript, reactjs, version, vite, downgrade

I installed Vite @4.2.1 in my project. I want to downgrade it to version @2.5.10
because, my app is not reloading when a component is modified. How can I do it?

`VITE v4.2.1  ready in 469 ms`

Searched on the internet and did not get any answers. Can I downgrade it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
npm install <package>@<version>
```

In case you have components, you might consider updating their code.

Example:

```
npm install vite@2.5.10
```